# Character encoding for reading text file from jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding, get

I am using jquery get to read in a text file.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    async: false,
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "utf-8"
});
$.get('test.txt', 'text')
.success(function (d)
{
    alert(d);
});
```

The contents of the text file are as follows.. "©e" (without speech marks). Two characters.

What's being returned from the ajax method is (I can't type it here) alt+65533

I must be doing something wrong and I don't know how to fix this. I've tried utf-8 but to no avail. What do I need to do to get this to work? Should I be using the ajax function instead of get?

Comment: Copy paste it here.. you can use `console.log`... `alert` is not copy-pasteable

Comment: It's not letting me copy it in. If you open a text file, hold down alt and press on your keypad 065533 it will come up

Comment: Use `console.log` and copy it from there. Do not use alert - because it is not copy-pasteable

Comment: Sorry for the delay in writing back. I used console.log (which I should be using anyway) and it's come back with �e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the text file in an editor, and when you are in the Save As dialog, select UTF-8 for the encoding.

You have saved the file in Windows-1252/ANSI/ISO-88591 encoding right now, you need to fix that.

Comment: That worked. I didn't think about the file itself. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @codemonkey yes, with character encodings there are always 2 sides to it: the declared encoding (which can be wrong, like in your case you declared UTF-8 but the file was actually ANSI) and the actual physical encoding. The declaration is needed because one cannot determine character encoding just from seeing the bytes.